# Can I create a cast from a composite (table or row) type to a domain?

Tags: postgresql, cast, composite-types, domain

Let's say I have a simple table `foo`, and [domain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/domains.html) `bar`

```
CREATE TABLE foo(x)
AS VALUES (1),(2),(3);

CREATE DOMAIN bar AS text;
```

Is it possible to make a cast such that I can do

```sql
SELECT foo::bar FROM foo;
```

To start this, I create a function which takes a `foo` to a `bar`,

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION foo_to_bar(t foo)
RETURNS bar
AS $$
  SELECT FORMAT('%s AS BAR', t.x)::bar
$$
LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE;
```

I can see this works,

```
SELECT foo_to_bar(foo), pg_typeof(foo_to_bar(foo)) FROM foo;
 foo_to_bar | pg_typeof 
------------+-----------
 1 AS BAR   | bar
 2 AS BAR   | bar
 3 AS BAR   | bar
```

But when I do,

```sql
CREATE CAST (foo as bar) WITH FUNCTION foo_to_bar;
```

I get this weird warning,

> WARNING:  cast will be ignored because the target data type is a domain

And the result is even more bizzare,

```
$ SELECT foo::bar, pg_typeof(foo::bar) FROM foo;
 foo | pg_typeof 
-----+-----------
 (1) | bar
 (2) | bar
 (3) | bar
(3 rows)
```

You can see that we're returning the right type, but the value isn't what I would expect. I would expect this to produce the same value as the above where I use `foo_to_bar`.

- Is it possible to cast to a domain type?
- If no, what does the above do? Why do I get `(1)`, `(2)`, and `(3)`?

Answer (score 3):

You'll get the `(1)` result even without creating the cast or the function. That's simply the notation for the whole row from foo when treated as a record.

```
CREATE TABLE foo(x) AS VALUES (1),(2),(3);
CREATE DOMAIN bar AS text;
SELECT foo::bar, pg_typeof(foo::bar) FROM foo;
 foo │ pg_typeof 
─────┼───────────
 (1) │ bar
 (2) │ bar
 (3) │ bar
```

Custom casts to/from domains aren't supported:

```
A cast to or from a domain type currently has no effect. Casting to or from a domain uses the casts associated with its underlying type.
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-createcast.html

@ilmari points out that a cast to text works:

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo_to_bar(t foo)
RETURNS bar
AS $$
  SELECT FORMAT('%s AS BAR', t.x)::bar
$$
LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE;

CREATE CAST (foo as text) WITH FUNCTION foo_to_bar;

SELECT foo::bar, pg_typeof(foo::bar) FROM foo;
   foo    │ pg_typeof 
──────────┼───────────
 1 AS BAR │ bar
 2 AS BAR │ bar
 3 AS BAR │ bar

SELECT foo::text, pg_typeof(foo::bar) FROM foo;
   foo    │ pg_typeof 
──────────┼───────────
 1 AS BAR │ bar
 2 AS BAR │ bar
 3 AS BAR │ bar
```

Comment: Here you have your first 10 points :^)

Answer (score 0):

## Polymorphism as a Workaround

No you can't use a cast on a domain. But, if you're trying to skirt the complexity of having different function names and different arguments you can easily do that with the polymorphism support in PostgreSQL aside from the cast system.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION to_bucket_path(t table1) AS $$ ;defn; $$ LANGUAGE SQL;
CREATE FUNCTION to_bucket_path(t table2) AS $$ ;defn; $$ LANGUAGE SQL;
CREATE FUNCTION to_bucket_path(t table2) AS $$ ;defn; $$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

This will allow the syntax like this,

```sql
SELECT to_bucket_path(foo) FROM foo;
SELECT to_bucket_path(bar) FROM bar;
SELECT to_bucket_path(baz) FROM baz;
```

This would work, and it's close to the idea of:

```sql
SELECT foo::bucketpath FROM foo;
SELECT bar::bucketpath FROM bar;
SELECT baz::bucketpath FROM baz;
```